# Serverless framework deployment with external dependencies problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, requirements.txt

I have two lambda functions: lambda_fn_1 and lambda_fn_2 with the following dependecies:
1. lambda_fn_1 has "requests" module as the external dependecy
2. lambda_fn_2 has "psycopg2" module as the external dependecy

I want to deploy theses functions to AWS Lambda using the serverless framework. Here is my serverless.yaml template file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrMOV.png

I have created a requirements.txt file that has the both the dependecies. Now I wish to deploy lambda_fn_1 only with the "requests" dependecy module and lambda_fn_2 with only "psycopg2" dependecy modules. What change should be made to the serverless template file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having the one single requirement.txt file that has both the dependencies like this:

```
- requirements.txt:
    - requests
    - psycopg2
```

Have two separate requirement.txt files, each for one lambda function that has only the required dependencies for that lambda function. This would be the new folder structure:

```
- lambda_fn_1:
    - requirements.txt (requests)
    - handler.py
- lambda_fn_2:
    - requirements.txt (psycopg2)
    - handler.py
```

and this will the modification in the serverless template:

```
- lambda_fn_1:
    handler: handler.lambda_handler
    module: lambda_fn_1
- lambda_fn_2:
    handler: handler.lambda_handler
    module: lambda_fn_2
```

"**module**" depicts the place where the framework picks up the requirements.txt file and thus, it will only pick up the file in that particular folder.